# Loop Through PSOBJECT To Compare Values to a String

Tags: powershell

Working on a script to get the status of Windows Defender components. Running into a challenge looping through the results from Get-MpComputerStatus as I'm wanting to write out which components are enabled and disabled.

The issue that I'm running into is I'm not able to get the specific value from the PSOBJECT and only get everything.

```
#Microsoft Defender Statuses
$DefenderStatus = Get-MpComputerStatus | select-object AMServiceEnabled, AntispywareEnabled, AntivirusEnabled, BehaviorMonitorEnabled, IoavProtectionEnabled, IsTamperProtected, IsVirtualMachine, NISEnabled, OnAccessProtectionEnabled, RealTimeProtectionEnabled

#Write results to a PSOBJECT
$result =  ([ordered]@{

            'Anti-Virus'=$DefenderStatus.AntivirusEnabled
            'Anti-Malware'=$DefenderStatus.AMServiceEnabled
            'Anti-Spyware'=$DefenderStatus.AntispywareEnabled
            'Behavior Monitor'=$DefenderStatus.BehaviorMonitorEnabled
            'Office-Anti-Virus'=$DefenderStatus.IoavProtectionEnabled
            'NIS'=$DefenderStatus.NISEnabled
            'Access Protection'=$DefenderStatus.OnAccessProtectionEnabled
            'R-T Protection'=$DefenderStatus.RealTimeProtectionEnabled

            })


foreach ($Status in $result)
{
   If ($Status.Values -eq $false)
   {
        Write-Host "$Status.Keys is Disabled"
        $Disabled = $Disabled + ", "  + $Status
   }
   Else
   {
        Write-Host "$Status.Keys is Enabled"
        $Enabled = $Enabled + ", "  + $Status

   }
}
```

Comment: You are not storing the properties in a PsObject, but in an ordered Hashtable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Theo comments](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo), you're storing the results in an [*ordered hash table*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary?view=net-6.0), if you want to iterate over the *Key-Value pairs* you could use [`.GetEnumerator()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.getenumerator?view=net-6.0) or `.Keys` property or `.get_Keys()` method, for example:

```
$result = [ordered]@{
    'Anti-Virus'        = $true
    'Anti-Malware'      = $true
    'Anti-Spyware'      = $false
    'Behavior Monitor'  = $false
    'Office-Anti-Virus' = $true
    'NIS'               = $false
    'Access Protection' = $true
    'R-T Protection'    = $true
}

foreach($pair in $result.GetEnumerator()) {
    # If the Value is $true
    if($pair.Value) {
        "{0} is Enabled" -f $pair.Key
        continue
    }
    # If we're here last condition was $false
    "{0} is Disabled" -f $pair.Key
}
```

However, since `$DefenderStatus` seem to be an *object* you could also do the following (**if it was an `object[]` (*array of objects*) this would need to be changed**):

```
$DefenderStatus = [PsCustomobject]@{
    'Anti-Virus'        = $true
    'Anti-Malware'      = $true
    'Anti-Spyware'      = $false
    'Behavior Monitor'  = $false
    'Office-Anti-Virus' = $true
    'NIS'               = $false
    'Access Protection' = $true
    'R-T Protection'    = $true
}

foreach($object in $DefenderStatus.PSObject.Properties) {
    # Property Value
    if($object.Value) {
        "{0} is Enabled" -f $object.Name # Property Name
        continue
    }
    "{0} is Disabled" -f $object.Name
}
```

Comment: Nicely done; just a quibble: the correct case of the accessor method is `.get_Keys()` (you can see all accessor methods if you pipe to `Get-Member -Force`). An alternative is to use `.psbase.Keys`. As for the backstory behind why an entry with key `Keys` unfortunately shadows the type-native `.Keys` property (ditto for `Values`), see [GitHub issue #7758](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7758).

Comment: @mklement0 updated thanks, there is no problem using the method name capitalized tho right?

Comment: Thanks for updating. You are correct: in PowerShell there's no problem with case variations (that's why I characterized my comment as a "quibble" - it is of no real consequence, but seeing the correct case makes some people - possibly including me - feel better :)